# Why does firebase verifyIdToken fail on one device after same user logs in on another device?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I can successfully log a user into firebase with the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and then store the generated id token in local storage.

That's all working fine and well.

When I log that same user in on another device I get a new id token and store it.

Now the first device will fail to verify the stored id token, probably because it doesn't match the newer token. But shouldn't firebase recognize both of these id tokens as valid until they expire?

What should the approach be to get firebase to accept all current active tokens?

Comment: The ID tokens on different devices should be unrelated to each other. In fact, the server is mostly stateless in how it treats ID tokens, it has no memory from one ID token it verified to the next. If you're having problems with ID tokens being verified, it'd really help if you can show the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which any of us can reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That was my understanding too, that firebase would have no issue verifying either token. 
 I will add some of my code and structure in case that helps highlight what the cause is.

Comment: well, turns out I wasn't handling my localstorage token correctly and it wasn't getting sent with my auth requests oops!